# centering the table generated by kable function of knitr package

Tags: r, knitr, centering

I am using the `kable()` function of knitr package to produce a nice book quality table in a pdf document. The output is as below where the table is placed on the left.
[image]

I want to place the table at the center as below. 
[image]

I would appreciate if anyone can give some advice. I know I can do it using `xtable`. Is there any way I can do it directly using kable?

The complete reproducible knitr code (.Rnw file) is as below;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

<<results='asis'>>=
library(knitr)
kable(head(women), format='latex', booktabs=TRUE)
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can provide a custom LaTeX preamble to center all your tables like suggested at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6036/2878

Comment: @daroczig That suggestion did not work for me.

Comment: Mahbubul, depending on what version of `pandoc` you (RStudio) are using, you might want to update the `ctable` or `longtable` environment instead of `tabular`

Answer (score 22):

With [`kableExtra`](http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/), you can set the alignment by using:

```
kable(head(women), "latex", booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling(position = "center")
```

http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf

Comment: Nice! Easy as taking candy from the child.